# How could I avoid Oracle rounding number with 20 decimal places automatically?

Tags: oracle11g, floating-point

I have a Oracle Database version 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 and after updating a numeric (30,20) row, I discovered some awful behavior. Running `update table set column = 9999999999.00390625 where someClause` was okay, but selecting the same value resulted in `9999999999.003910450000000000`.

I know about [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) and noticed stack overflow's warning about it. My question is:

Using Oracle 11g, is there any method or means available to deal with this imprecision? I thought about saving my number in 2 pieces (decimal and integer parts) and using some logic to sum them up before giving it back to who requested. But is this some boilerplate code?

**EDIT**

This is what all_tab_cols returned with respective where clause:

```
DATA_TYPE   NUMBER
DATA_LENGTH 22
DATA_PRECISION  30
DATA_SCALE  20
NULLABLE    Y
COLUMN_ID   2
DATA_DEFAULT    <Long>
NUM_DISTINCT    12
LOW_VALUE   80
HIGH_VALUE  BE640D51
DENSITY 0,0833333333333333
NUM_NULLS   0
NUM_BUCKETS 1
LAST_ANALYZED   07/07/2011 15:49:11
SAMPLE_SIZE 56  
GLOBAL_STATS    YES
USER_STATS  NO
AVG_COL_LEN 4
CHAR_LENGTH 0
V80_FMT_IMAGE   NO
DATA_UPGRADED   YES
HIDDEN_COLUMN   NO
VIRTUAL_COLUMN  NO
SEGMENT_COLUMN_ID   2
INTERNAL_COLUMN_ID  2
HISTOGRAM   NONE
```

All empty column values were omitted, as well as column, table and user names.
I checked that no triggers are applied to this table and our Java application showed same value as PL/SQL Developer (pink one) as a proof this isn't some client problem.

Actually, using `0.00390625` instead of `9999999999.00390625` resulted no misbehavior, kind of proving the floating point problem's cause.

Comment: The ANSI numeric type is treated the same as the natove number type ([doc ref](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-0BC16006-32F1-42B1-B45E-F27A494963FF). What is the actual column data type - what DDL was used to create it, and what does `all_tab_cols` report, for the actual data type, scale and precision? Also, which client are you seeing this is; and can you confirm the actual stored value via `dump()`; and have you ruled out someone else, or a trigger, modifynig the value you entered?

Comment: Well, a `number(30,20)` column, which is what you seem to have, doesn't display the behaviour you describe. You only have to worry about that kind of discrepancy with floats - and that isn't what you have... [This demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5e8b8ef6843e8235d51405cc38e015f0) is on 11.2.0.2, and works the same on 11.2.0.5; it's unlikely there's a bug that horrendous specific to 11.2.0.3.